# Basis for a chain

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a chain of linear subspaces $L_\alpha$ of space $L$. There is no linear subspace that for all $\alpha\in A$ contains $L_\alpha$ or is contained in it. In other words, the chain is maximal. For such $\alpha\in A_0$ that $M_\alpha=L_\alpha\setminus\bigcup\limits_{L_\beta\subset L_\alpha}L_\beta\neq\emptyset$ one chooses a vector $v_\alpha\in M_\alpha$. The set $V=\{v_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A_0}$ is linear independent. Is $V$ a basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [dxdy.ru](http://dxdy.ru/post1023831.html#p1023831) I got  counterexample to the statement. Let $e_n, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ are basis vectors of $L$, $L_n=span({...,e_{n-1},e_n})$. Chain $...\subset L_{n-1}\subset L_n\subset L_{n+1}\subset...$ is maximal, but vectors $v_n=e_n+e_{n-1}\in L_n\setminus L_{n-1}$ don't form basis of $L$.